# Django redirect to url with post data

Tags: python, django

I am in my views.py and I need to go to a url with post request along with post data.

I tried HttpResponseRedirect but it does not take post data as param.

```
class WebPaymentView(FormView):

    template_name = "payment/payment.html"
    form_class = NameForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # code
        return HttpResponseRedirect(url, data=data, content_type="application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
```

Last line gives error:

> TypeError: __init __() got an unexpected keyword argument 'data'

I want to post to this url as well as redirect to it. Any idea how?

Comment: Any alternative to this ? I am now using ajax call but django rest framework api url I need to call needs user auth token. P.S Newbie in Jquery/Ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server side cannot redirect the user and make it a post request. Based on the simple code shared, what I think you are looking for is the [action attribute of the Form html tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp).